# Live USB with two Operating Systems

Tags: live-usb

I know it is possible to dual boot a hard drive as a computer. But what if I want to create a USB stick that has two different "live sessions" on it. How would I go about doing this? I can't seem to find a way to do this in Startup Disks in Ubuntu.

I'd like to dual Ubuntu and Kali linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multi boot usb with multisystem: [MultiSystem – Create a MultiBoot USB from Linux](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)
Download the script, your favourite linux iso and using the multisystem transfer the isos to the usb. It will create a separate Grub menu on the USB with multiple choices.

It can boot Windows iso also.
When you have a dos or windows iso, you can find the menu entry under GrubforDOS.